# Alternative to if else block - checking a number is between 2 numbers

Tags: java, if-statement

Currently I have a block similar to below:

```
if (number< 11 && number>= 5) {
    return 1;
} else if (number< 15 && number>= 11) {
    return 2;
} else if (number< 45 && number>= 15) {
    return 3;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might use a `switch` statement, but it would not be shorter.

Comment: In your case you can drop the second condition in all `else if`-statements. Those are taken care of before.

Comment: A switch case statement wouldn't work for those conditionals, only for specific integers

Comment: People: please understand that the usage of multiples of 5 **is just an example**

Comment: Can you please edit your question in order to show that the numbers aren't always multiple of 5?

Comment: I think I prefer your way in terms of clarity for a small set. If there were a large number of ranges (or it were repeated) then you should define a "table of" ranges (start, end number) mapped to value and methods providing the lookup for a value. For the "table" abstraction, I'd consider a proper `Range` class or the array way in Luiggi Mendoza's answer.

Answer (score 10):

How about calculating the result?

```
return number / 5;
```

Edit:

As noted by the comments, this only works if `number` is >= 0. Simply add an appropriate if statement if that is not the case.

Comment: This won't work if the numbers are different from multiple of 5...

Comment: Also doesn't work if you do (1 - 5) / 5

Comment: Actually it won't work at all.  This highlights the need for debugging.

Comment: Well, good edit, but I voted for the guy who understood this at the time of posting.

Comment: @0A0D added clarifying comment.

Comment: @paddy Fair enough, so have I. :-)

Comment: won't this return a decimal?

Comment: After OP's question edition, this fails miserably :).

Comment: what if number = 40? his method should return 3, yours 8

Comment: This is still wrong because it won't return the numbers the OP originally intended to return

Comment: @0A0D We are dealing with Java's integer division, i.e. the result of a division between two integers is also an integer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agreed, the question has been changed substantially...

Comment: @user902383 My answer was correct when i submitted it, however the question has been updated since then.

Comment: @matsev: What does that have to do with anything? If you take 40 / 5 it equals 8. Does that return 1, 2, 3 ? No, it doesn't. Therefore, you did not create the equivalent of the OP's question with just your return.

Comment: @0A0D In one of your comments, you asked if my answer returns a decimal. I replied that it returns an integer (i.e. a non-decimal). Secondly, the OP has not given any clues to how input values outside the specified range should be treated (neither in the original question nor after the update). Appropriate actions may include return 1, 2, 3,  throw IllegalArgumentException, or return any other int. The OP's code does not compile, so we don't know. I provided a simple solution that was valid within the specified range, which also happened to compile for values outside the specified range.

Comment: @matsev: Ok, I see which comment you were replying to now. OP's code compiles fine when put into a program. It is just a snippet. If you read closely, you can see he is looking for a way to simplify the if/else statements. While you attempted to do that, it does not return the original 1, 2, or 3 for the given ranges so you failed to properly provide a solution. It's very obvious.

Comment: @0A0D Let's wrap the current snippet in a method: 
    `int calculate(int number) {
        if (number< 11 && number>= 5) {
            return 1;
        } else if (number< 15 && number>= 11) {
            return 2;
        } else if (number< 45 && number>= 15) {
            return 3;
        }
    }`
Compilation result: "Compilation failure: missing return statement".
Cause: There is no default return statement, no trailing `else`-branch nor any input validation that handles numbers < 5 and numbers >= 45.

Comment: Again, it's a snippet and you failed to provide a return for the ranges originally shown.

Comment: @0A0D Scrolling this page, I acknowledge that the suggested solutions treat input values outside the specified range in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to do some arethmetic

```
return (int)number/5
```

which will do exactly what your code is doing

You can do similar so long as your ranges follow just about any mathematical pattern

Comment: This won't work if the numbers are different from multiple of 5...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza did the OP ask us to do it for numbers that are different from multiples of 5?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza do you think a moderately intelligent OP could take the same concept and do it for numbers that are different from multiples of 5?

Comment: **Read the title**: *checking a number is between 2 numbers*. The case of 5 is just a sample...

Comment: Well, the problem is that this allows for numbers less than 5 or greater than 20. You can't just replace what he currently has because you didn't check the range.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This can easily be fixed with a single `if` statement, which I think is what the OP wanted - they want an alternative to clunky `else` clauses.

Comment: what if number = 40? his method should return 3, yours 8

Comment: @user902383: Yes, Sam's calculation doesn't adapt to the OP's original question well

Answer (score 5):

I would use two arrays, 1 to hold the numbers to compare and other to hold the answers. Showing a very simple example of this approach:

```
public int getResult(int number) {
    int[] results = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] numbers = { 5, 11, 15, 45 };
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
        if (between(number, numbers[i], numbers[i+1])) {
            return results[i];
        }
    }
    //return a default value
    //return results[results.length - 1];
    return 0;
}

public boolean between(int x, int a, int b) {
    return (x >= a && x < b);
}
```

Comment: assuming you always input `numbers` in ascending order (which makes sense) you can eliminate half of the comparisons

Comment: @Heuster I guess this can be done searching the number using binary search, right?

Comment: that would be even better :-) I actually just meant a linear search only checking `number < numbers[i]`

Comment: @Heuster I coded it in the way you can stop using `int`s and convert both methods to support `<T extends Comparable>`. Still, it is a first idea.

Comment: This isn't simplified though, its more complicated :)

Comment: @0A0D the only complication I can see here is having the arrays (or to be more generic, data sources) to use when comparing data and when having the result. Apart of that, the solution is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: But you doubled the lines of code and made it a little more overengineered.. if there was a way to simplify it properly into one return statement, that would be ideal.

Comment: @0A0D having more lines of code or even more characters in a line of code is not a precise way to measure the complexity of a method.

Comment: Huh? Lines of code is a particular metric when measuring cyclomatic complexity. It's used by all kinds of tools. Check out McCabe.

Comment: @0A0D also, OP just shows 3 comparisons. This way is meant to work for a more generic problem, when you have like 9001 test cases.

Comment: Perfect, but we are just talking about a small range here :)

Comment: @0A0D this is a test, for the sake of god. If you're against this method and have a better idea, post an answer.

Comment: I have been thinking of one but if you don't want constructive criticism, then don't post. The problem with the OP's question is there are very little if any ways to simplify the problem beyond the if statements without making it overly complicated. That would be the answer I might post. You yourself also commented on others posts so don't get upset when someone criticizes yours. By the way, I upvoted your post.. the others are all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) library, it provides a simplified way of checking ranges instead of the garden-variety if-statement. It is an improvement over the lines of code in your method. However, the one-time improvement by doing this is questionable, but it does make it more readable in my opinion.

In your case, you could have a method which provides for a low endpoint and high endpoint. Your logic matches the `closedOpen` of `Ranges`: `{x | a <= x < b}`

```
private int getNumber(int low, int high, int n)
{
   if (Ranges.closedOpen(low, high).contains(n))
   {
      // return the number
   }
}
```

But that's slightly more complicated because you are adding complexity with more if statements to know which number to return. It'd be nice if there was a dictionary for this sort of thing and there is!

It looks like you want a [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html). Specifically you can use the [`floorKey`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorKey%28K%29) operation.

The `floorKey(K key)` method is used to return the **greatest key less than or equal** to the given key, or **null if there is no such key.**

Here's an example:

```
NavigableMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

map.put(0, 0);          
map.put(5, 1);
map.put(11, 2);
map.put(15, 3);
map.put(46, 0);

System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(6)));     // 1
System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(11)));    // 2
System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(23)));    // 3
```

Note that there are also `ceilingKey`, `lowerKey`, `higherKey`, and also `…Entry` instead of `…Key` operations as well which returns a `Map.Entry<K,V>` instead of just the `K`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that numbers are of multiples of 5 as @Luggi commented you can simply do

```
return (number - 5) / 5;
```

Comment: This won't work if the numbers are different from multiple of 5...

Comment: And Op showed us that options aren't always multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Could return the largest whole number when divided by 5.

```
return Math.floor(number/5)
```