# Storing tables in java for refrencing

Tags: java, optimization, collections

So the question is regarding optimization of the code. I have a table for retirement date which im going to list below

```
 Year of Birth                              Full Retirement Age
 1937 or earlier.............................65
 1938........................................65 years 2 months
 1939........................................65-4
 1934.......................................65-6
 .
 .
 .and the list is a long list
```

What i want to do is to store this table in a in list object or something so that I can pass in the year of birth in a method and the list object and get back the corresponding retirement age. I dont want to have a lot of If and Else Statements in my code because the list is so damn big and the code will be confusing.

What can be a possible solution for this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325056/1065197

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using map instead of list. Use year of birth as key, so that you can directly get the associated value from the map.

Comment: what if two persons born in same year ??

Comment: Then they would have the same retirement age...that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can use map but there is a chance for duplicate keys.

Two persons can born in  same year.

Use `MultiMap`

> A [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29) that can hold duplicate key-value pairs and that maintains the insertion ordering of values for a given key. See the Multimap documentation for information common to all multimaps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map. Map is a List object with `Key:Value`.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put('1937', 65);
...
```

To go through a map you can use this:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

You can change values for `<String, Object>` as you wish (Integer, Date... or whatever). Always follow the same order `<KeyType, ValueType>`

Comment: what if two persons born in same year ?

Comment: Then, the best way I suggest you is to add the map to the `User` class. I mean, that if you have a class called `User` (for example), build the map as a class property `private String name; private Map<...> map = new HashMap<...>, etc.` Each class instantation will have his own map and you can get from each one it's value with a custom `getter`, like `getRetirementAge(String year) {...}`. I don't know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store your list/table into a HashMap...then retrieve from your method, something like:

```
public String getRetirementAge(String yearOfBirth) {
    return yourMap.get(yearOfBirth);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data for every year i would use a java map  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html where the key is the year and the value is the retirement value.

This would give you an O(1)

If you have sparse data and you have somehow to calculate the nearest year you could either use a sorted List and use Binary search which gives you an O(logn) or even use a B-tree.

BR,
David

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you store this information in a database, especially if the list is a very long list (which you say it is). There will be many optimizations that come from using a database. For one thing, you won't have to store that huge list in memory. For another, SQL queries for data are often much faster than data structures in code. Martin Fowler has an (admittedly old) article about this at http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/dblogic.html. The other thing you gain from putting this in a database is that this is the type of list that is likely to change. They are already talking about adjusting retirement age in order to save social security. It is much easier to update data in a database than it is to edit code and recompile / redeploy.

The type of database you use can be NoSQL or relational, embedded or online. That decision I'll leave up to you. It will be a bonus for you if there is already a database available to this application for other reasons.